# How to get UNIQUE count from subquery?

Tags: php, mysql

Here is the query:

```
    SELECT count(a.id) as itemCount, 
           concat(a.firstname, ' ', a.lastname) as name, 
           oi.status, a.id as adminID, 
           (SELECT count(a.id) as oldItemsCount 
                   FROM bl_orderitems oi, 
                        bl_researcher r,             
                        tbladmins a 
                   WHERE oi.status='Pending' AND 
                         r.id=oi.researcherid AND 
                         r.researchermanagerid=a.id AND
                         DATE(oi.regdate)=DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY))
                   as oldItemCount
    FROM bl_orderitems oi, 
           bl_researcher r,
           tbladmins a 
    WHERE oi.status in ('Pending', 'QA') AND
           r.id=oi.researcherid AND 
           r.researchermanagerid=a.id 
    GROUP BY 
          name, adminID, oi.status;
```

This query should return something like:

```
 itemCount    name            status    adminID  oldItemCount 
    5         John McKay      Pending      20        125
    15        Clown Ho        QA           12        125
    39        Jack Fell       Pending      13        125
    5         Mark Grunigen   Pending       2        125
    1         Kim Jun Li      QA            2        125
    206       Abama Oladen    Pending       4        125
```

WHILE I'm trying to achieve that it returns UNIQUE oldItemCount.

oldItemCount should be count(a.id) that suite "`DATE(oi.regdate)=DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY))`"

If i try with DISTINCT on subquery, it says `Operand should contain 1 column(s)`

Comment: Try `count(distinct ...)`. Check: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count

Comment: @Barranka Doesn't work, return same oldItemCount for all rows :S

Comment: did you use it in your subquery?

Comment: @Barranka Yes, as in "SELECT count(DISTINCT oi.id)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is [COUNT(DISTINCT)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count-distinct).

EDIT: according to your comments, You should try something like this:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT oi.id) as itemCount, 
       concat(a.firstname, ' ', a.lastname) as name, 
       oi.status, a.id as adminID, 
       (SELECT count(oi2.id) as oldItemsCount 
               FROM bl_orderitems oi2, 
                    bl_researcher r2
               WHERE oi2.status='Pending' AND 
                     r2.id=oi.researcherid AND 
                     r2.researchermanagerid=a.id AND
                     DATE(oi2.regdate)=DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY))
               as oldItemCount
FROM bl_orderitems oi, 
       bl_researcher r,
       tbladmins a 
WHERE oi.status in ('Pending', 'QA') AND
       r.id=oi.researcherid AND 
       r.researchermanagerid=a.id 
GROUP BY 
      name, adminID, oi.status;
```

It's simpler and may fit your needs.

Comment: Returns 4 for all rows, which is incorect :S

Comment: Well, I guess your subquery is missing some condition to join with the main query.

Comment: You should probably choose different table aliases in your main query and your subquery, at least to be more explicit.

Comment: I think what you want to achieve is not COUNT(DISTINCT a.id), but maybe something like COUNT(DISTINCT oi.id)? What is an item? In which table is it? You need to pass to COUNT the appropriate column.